# SQL: Unsual names

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to select some information which is inside a table with the name `online-players` using Left join in `SQL` however, ever time I run the code it just returns the following error.

```
"Unknown column 'ontime' in 'field list'"
```

I am assuming its because of the `-` in the name of the table that course the error.

Is there anyway of going around it so it still gets the information?

Comment: please post your query. It is probably as simple as placing backticks around the table/column names but it would be helpful to see the query.

Comment: does the table actually contain the column `ontime`?

Comment: My guess is that a trip to the opticians is in order.

Comment: And try to avoid using names with special characters in future designs.

Answer (score 1):

That's not true, that error will be generated only when the corresponding field name doesn't exist. However you can enclose field and table names with backticks to be sure

Answer (score 1):

Backticks are required, that's all.

Answer (score -1):

You can use backticks (`) to refer to the table.

```
select * from `online-players`
```

This is provided that you don't have a typo in your query and such.

Comment: Never recommend using select *. It is a very poor practice.

Comment: [Never?](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a9034%20%22select%20*%20from%22%20is%3aanswer)